# Properties of the Weighted Mean using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, means, central-limit-theorem

Consider the following set of $N$ Independent Random Variables:

- $X_1 = \{x_{11}, x_{12}, \dots x_{1n_1}\}$
- $X_2 = \{x_{21}, x_{22}, \dots, x_{2n_2}\}$
- etc.
- $X_N = \{x_{N1}, x_{N2}, \dots, x_{Nn_n}\}$

Each of these Random Variables has:

- A sample size of $N_i$ random realizations (i.e. $X_1$ has $n_1$ realizations, $X_2$ has $n_2$ realizations, etc.)
- Unknown Probability Distributions

Using the Central Limit Theorem, we can argue that regardless of the underlying Probability Distribution:

$$E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_i} \frac{x_i}{n_i} = \mu_i$$
$$E(X_i^2) - E(X_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{n} = \sigma^2_i $$
$$\mu_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$$

By extension, I could then say that if I define a new Random Variable $W$:

$$W = \frac{\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \dots + \mu_N}{N}$$

$$ E(W) = \frac{1}{N} \left( E(\mu_1) + E(\mu_2) + \dots + E(\mu_N) \right) = \frac{1}{N} \left( \mu_1 + \mu_2 + \dots + \mu_N \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\mu_i}{N}$$

$$ Var(W) = \frac{1}{N^2} \left( Var(\mu_1) + Var(\mu_2) + \dots + Var(\mu_N) \right) = \frac{1}{N^2} \left( \sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2 + \dots + \sigma^2_N \right) = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma^2_i $$

And then again using Central Limit Theorem, we could again argue that:
$$W \sim N \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\mu_i}{N}, \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma^2_i \right)$$

**My Question:** Given that each of these random variables $X_i$ have a large enough sample size,  can $W$ be considered as a "suitable" (i.e. dominant estimator, admissible, statistical properties such as unbiasedness, consistency, minimum variance, etc.) estimator for estimating the population mean instead of using the Weighted Mean (e.g. weighting proportional to counts $n_i$, weighting proportional to $\sigma^2_i$)?

Thanks!

Comment: This post seems fairly confused. A few points off the bat. First, your $X_j$ are not equal to the sets of their observations. That doesn’t make sense. Second, the central limit theorem does not tell you that the sample mean equals the expectation. You’re thinking of the law of large numbers, but even that doesn’t give you equality, just convergence. Similar for the sample variance. Third, the central limit theorem doesn’t tell you how $\mu_i$ is distributed. Just convergence in distribution to a normal distribution. And you need conditions on the RVs. I’d recommend clearing up these issues.

Comment: Also, in addition what Joe said, the term "unknown probability distributions" usually means that the parameters of the distribution are are not known either. Therefore, $\mu_{i}$ and $\sigma^2_{i}$ need to be replaced by their respective sample estimates.

Comment: thank you everyone - reading your comments, I now realize how poorly this post is written. Can we all vote to close it? I will make a new post. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are authorized to delete your own post without requiring anyone else to vote on it.

Comment: Yes, you can just delete it.

Comment: This expression, $\mu_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$, makes no sense.

Comment: What is $W$ an estimator of?